# Creating groups of data in ASP.Net gridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am using GridViewHelper to show gridview data in specific groupwise.
but my output not display as per the requirment.
[Current Gridview Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcASp.png)

i am using the following code:

```
protected void gvViewReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewHelper helper = new GridViewHelper(this.gvViewReport);
            helper.RegisterGroup("BranchCode", true, true);
            helper.GroupHeader += new GroupEvent(helper_GroupHeader);
            helper.ApplyGroupSort();
          
        }
```

BranchCode repeat.
[image]

Comment: Why are you using webforms in 2021? It's been effectively obsolete for 13 years now.

Comment: Your `RowDataBound` event-handler will be invoked _for every row_ - that's not what you want.